# Dynamic width div and ellipsis text

Tags: css, html, dynamic, width

I'm attempting to place 4 divs floating next to each other, in which the first two must be placed on the left side, the fourth one should be on the right, and the third one must take the width remaining between both sides. So, divs #1, #2 and #4 have predefined widths but the #3 is dynamic.
Also, this dynamic width div has two text lines (two spans) and I'd like for them to support ellipsis when the page resizing prevents the full reading of their text. Right now, at a given point, div #4 moves down when there's not enough room for it (due to the span's text width). Can this be accomplished, and if so without Javascript? I'm looking for a IE9 minimum support.

Here's what I came up with:
    http://jsfiddle.net/NMrks/aySyu/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="blockA">A</div>
    <div class="blockB">B</div>
    <div class="blockC">
        <div class="blockC_container">
            <span class="lineA">Text text text from line A</span>
            <span class="lineB">Text text text text text from line B</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blockD">
            <span>D</span>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
height: 60px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
min-width: 340px;
}

.container .blockA {
width: 54px;
height: 100%;
float: left;
display: block;
background-color: #ff00ff;
}

.container .blockB {
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
float: left;
display: block;
background: #df8505;
}

.container .blockC {
height: 100%;
float: left;
display: block;
background: #ff7d7b;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container .blockC .lineA {
line-height: 2.0em;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
}

.container .blockC .lineB {
line-height: 1.0em;
display: block;
}

.container .blockD {
width: 64px;
height: 100%;
float: right;
display: block;
background: #df8505;
}
```

I tried playing the with the 100% width, setting margins according to the other surrounding divs widths, flexbox, etc., but I couldn't figure out a way to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this, which addresses both issues:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.container {
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    min-width: 340px;
}

.container .blockA {
    width: 54px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ff00ff;
}

.container .blockB {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background: #df8505;
}

.container .blockC {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #ff7d7b;
}

.container .blockC_container p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.lineA, .lineB {margin: 0;}

.container .blockC .lineA {
    line-height: 2.0em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container .blockC .lineB {
    line-height: 1.0em;
}

.container .blockD {
    width: 64px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    background: #df8505;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="blockA">A</div>
    <div class="blockB">B</div>

    <div class="blockD">
            <span>D</span>
    </div>

    <div class="blockC">
        <div class="blockC_container">
            <p class="lineA">Text text text from line A</p>
            <p class="lineB">Text text text text text from line B Text text text text text from line BText text text text text from line BText text text text text from line B</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div stye="clear:both"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There are other ways to get the third column to take up all the space, but placing it after the other column in the HTML and removing its float is the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Small correction
blockA, blockC, blockD should have width:auto, otherwise their content will be overflowed outside.

updated sample with long AAA, BBB and  CCC  cells:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.container {
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    min-width: 340px;
}

.container .blockA {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ff00ff;
}

.container .blockB {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background: #df8505;
}

.container .blockC {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #ff7d7b;
}

.container .blockC_container p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.lineA, .lineB {margin: 0;}

.container .blockC .lineA {
    line-height: 2.0em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container .blockC .lineB {
    line-height: 1.0em;
}

.container .blockD {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    background: #df8505;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="blockA">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
    <div class="blockB">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>

    <div class="blockD">
            <span>DDDDDDDDDDDD</span>
    </div>

    <div class="blockC">
        <div class="blockC_container">
            <p class="lineA">Text text text from line A</p>
            <p class="lineB">Text text text text text from line B Text text text text text from line BText text text text text from line BText text text text text from line B</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div stye="clear:both"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v5Dns/3/